# SPP on Bluedroid

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluez, spp

I wanted to see if anyone has attempted to implement SPP on Bluedroid.  After looking at the stack source you can see clearly that the SPP_INCLUDED flag is false and there is no source for SPP in the directory that contains it.  I have a device that needs SPP and was looking for more information or experience from others.

I am looking at the BlueZ AOSP implementation concurrently with this idea.  This is where SPP seems to work just fine (basically all of standard BT, but BLE does not).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the use case here. But whatever you intend to do using SPP, you should be able to do with Bluetoothsocket APIs using some custom UUID.